# C Program Pig Latin Translator Errors - How to fix the errors?

Tags: c, string, char

example -> exampleyay but instead, xampleeay is printed. If it starts with a vowel(a,e,i,o,u), simply supposed to add 'yay' at the end. How do I fix that?

quick -> ickquay but instead, uickqay is printed. 'qu' are supposed to be treated as a letter pair together as a consonant. How do I fix that also?

y is only treated as a vowel after first occurrence, but I got that working.

All leading consonants are moved to the end of the word until it reaches the first vowel(including y), and adds 'ay' at the end. And that seems to be working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char v);

int main()
{
  char str1[50] = ""; 
  char str2[10] = "";
  int i;
  int length;

  printf("Pig Latin Translator\n");
  printf("----------------------\n");
  printf("Type a word: ");
  scanf("%s", str1);

  length = strlen(str1); 

  strncat(str2, str1,1); 

  for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    str1[i] = str1[i + 1];
  }

  strcat(str1, str2);

  strcat(str1, "ay");
  printf("%s", str1);
  return 0;
}


bool isVowel(char v) {
    if (v == 'A' || v == 'E' || v == 'I' || v == 'O' || v == 'U' ||
        v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `bool isVowel(char v) { return strchr("AEIOU", toupper(v)); }`

Answer (score 0):

The following program works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char v);

int main()
{
  char str1[50] = ""; 
  int i = 0;

  printf("Pig Latin Translator\n");
  printf("----------------------\n");
  printf("Type a word: ");
  scanf("%s", str1);

  if (toupper(str1[i]) == 'Y')
    i++;

  for (; !isVowel(str1[i]) && str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (toupper(str1[i]) == 'Q' && toupper(str1[i + 1]) == 'U')
      i++;
  }

  strncat(str1, str1, i);
  strcpy(str1, &str1[i]);

  if(i == 0)
    strcat(str1, "yay");
  else
    strcat(str1,"ay");

  printf("%s", str1);
  return 0;
}

bool isVowel(char v) { return strchr("AEIOUY", toupper(v)); }
```